# Data comparison issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the below sql query:

```
select @table1 as DataState, *  from
(select * from importedcsvclients 
except 
select * from tblClients) x
union all
select @table2 as DataState, *  from
(select * from tblClients 
except select *  
from importedcsvclients) x
```

The above code works fine, however, if table1 and table2 consist similar data, both records will show.

Can anyone assist me to make the query work as:

get the results of both table1 and table2, but only show table2 data if the same name doesn't exist in table1.

Thanks.

For Info:

```
table1
ID   Name
1    TestA
2    TestB    
3    TestC
4    TestD

table2
ID   Name
1    TestE
2    TestF    
3    TestG
4    TestD

Results:
Name     DataState
TestA    table1
TestB    table1
TestC    table1
TestD    table1
TestE    table2
TestF    table2
TestG    table2
```

Comment: By "show table2 data if data exist in table1", do you mean just the ID, or also the Name?

Comment: I think you meant the opposite (at least that's what your results show). Didn't you mean "only show table2 data if the name doesn't exist in table1"? You left table2's copy of TestD out of the results.

Comment: Hi Aaron, TestD from table2 should not be showing. The results should have TestA, TestB, TestC, TestD From table1 and TestE, TestF, TestG from table2. Thanks.

Comment: Hi John, ID does not matters, just as long the name are distinct.

Comment: I've updated the wording of the question to make that more clear. Please let me know if it seems more correct now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below now.
Thanks for all assistance.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @table1 + ''' AS DataState, * FROM
(SELECT ' + @columnlist + ' FROM ' + @table1 + '
    EXCEPT
SELECT ' + @columnlist + ' FROM ' + @table2 + ') x
    UNION
SELECT ''' + @table2 + ''' AS DataState, * from
    (SELECT ' + @columnlist + ' FROM ' + @table2 + '
        INTERSECT
    SELECT ' + @columnlist + ' FROM ' + @table1 +') x'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 3):

Very tempting to use `EXCEPT` but as you've found it is not always as straightforward to get the proper results from anything with a little complexity. Here's a try at the result you're after using a CTE:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(32));    
INSERT @table1 VALUES (1,'TestA'), (2,'TestB'), (3,'TestC'), (4,'TestD');

DECLARE @table2 TABLE(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(32));
INSERT @table2 VALUES (1,'TestE'), (2,'TestF'), (3,'TestG'), (4,'TestD');

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT m, Name, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY m)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT m = 'table1', Name FROM @table1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT m = 'table2', Name FROM @table2
  ) AS y
)
SELECT Name, DataState = m
  FROM x 
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY Name;
```

Results:

```
Name        DataState
---------   ---------
TestA       table1
TestB       table1
TestC       table1
TestD       table1
TestE       table2
TestF       table2
TestG       table2
```

Comment: Works Great... Btw, how can I remove the column 'm' as it is showing a column 'm' when I execute the query.

Comment: It shouldn't unless you changed my final SELECT list to SELECT * (which you shouldn't do).

Comment: I see. If instead of TestD showing table2, how can i tweak to show as table1? Thanks.

Comment: Um... TestD does show as table1, doesn't it? If you mean the other way around (again, as in my edit to your question), then changed `ORDER BY m` to `ORDER BY m DESC`.

Comment: Please be careful to say what you mean. That's twice where you're totally confusing people by stating the opposite of what you actually want.

Comment: Sorry Aaron, do you mind helping me one last part on this question? From your code, can I hide table2 records? Thank you very much.

Comment: Change the where clause to `WHERE rn = 1 AND DataState = 'table1'` or just `WHERE DataState = 'table1'` ... not entirely sure what the point of all the inner CTE work would be, but...

Comment: Hi Aaron, I tried with your method WHERE rn = 1 AND DataState = 'table1' , but it returns "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'table1'."

Comment: I suspect you didn't copy the code correctly. `'table1'` needs to be enclosed in single quotes, since it is a string, not a column or other identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In (pesudo) relational algebra:

```
table1 UNION ( table2 NOT MATCH table1 )
```

In TSQL (adding `DataState`):

```
SELECT ID, Name, 
       'table1' AS DataState
  FROM table1
UNION
SELECT ID, Name,
       'table2' AS DataState
  FROM table2
 WHERE Name NOT IN ( SELECT Name FROM table1 );
```

Including your sample data test data:

```
WITH table1 
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'TestA'),
                     (2, 'TestB'),    
                     (3, 'TestC'),
                     (4, 'TestD')
             ) AS T (ID, Name)
     ),
     table2
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'TestE'),
                     (2, 'TestF'),    
                     (3, 'TestG'),
                     (4, 'TestD')
             ) AS T (ID, Name)
     )
SELECT ID, Name, 
       'table1' AS DataState
  FROM table1
UNION
SELECT ID, Name,
       'table2' AS DataState
  FROM table2
 WHERE Name NOT IN ( SELECT Name FROM table1 );
```